# Sum of last 12 months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns (Year, Month, Value) like this in Sql Server :

| Year | Month | Value | ValueOfLastTwelveMonths |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | 30 | 30 |
| 2021 | 2 | 24 | 54 (30 + 24) |
| 2021 | 5 | 26 | 80 (54+26) |
| 2021 | 11 | 12 | 92 (80+12) |
| 2022 | 1 | 25 | 87 (SUM of values from 1 2022 TO 2 2021) |
| 2022 | 2 | 40 | 103 (SUM of values from 2 2022 TO 3 2021) |
| 2022 | 4 | 20 | 123 (SUM of values from 4 2022 TO 5 2021) |

I need a SQL request to calculate ValueOfLastTwelveMonths.

```sql
SELECT Year,
        Month,
        Value,
        SUM (Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, Month)
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Please don't use code markdown for *everything*, code markdown is for *code*. Also don't tag conflicting products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *much* easier if you have a row for each month and year, and then (if needed) you can filter the `NULL` rows out. The reason it's easier is because then you know how many rows you need to look back at: 11.

If you make a dataset of the years and months, you can then `LEFT JOIN` to your data, aggregate, and then finally filter the data out:

```
SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES(2021,1,30),
            (2021,2,24),
            (2021,5,26),
            (2021,11,12),
            (2022,1,25),
            (2022,2,40),
            (2022,4,20))V(Year,Month,Value);

GO
WITH YearMonth AS(
    SELECT YT.Year,
           V.Month
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Year
          FROM dbo.YourTable) YT
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12))V(Month)),
RunningTotal AS(
    SELECT YM.Year,
           YM.Month,
           YT.Value,
           SUM(YT.Value) OVER (ORDER BY YM.Year, YM.Month
                               ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Last12Months
    FROM YearMonth YM
         LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON YM.Year = YT.Year
                                   AND YM.Month = YT.Month)
SELECT Year,
       Month,
       Value,
       Last12Months
FROM RunningTotal
WHERE Value IS NOT NULL;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```